# EntityFramework 5 - Change Initial Order of Items in Collection (NavigationProperty)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

is it possible to change the item's order in a collection that is a navigationProperty?

sample:

A Entity "Order" has many "Item" Entities. One to Many Relation.

i want that all items of an order a sorted by the name. How could i do that without a query on the DbSet? I want that the items are sorted after i load them into the context.

Is this possible to manipulate the generated SQL Query from the EF to add a ORDER BY ?

Thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

No. You'll have to do that when you process the items in any way, e.g. for display.